Kafka connect doesn't accept custom SMT connector
I am running connect.standalone.bat locally and I am using a MongoDB Sink Connector. The records in the topic have date fields stored as Timestamp or ZonedDateTime, but either way mongo saves them as either long or string, not a native date object. I managed to convert them correctly using TimestampConverter$Value, but it doesn't work on nested fields - "tomatoes.lastUpdated" doesn't work. I decided to create a custom converter, created the jar and added it to my connectors path, but when I submit the updated properties.json to the connect server with this line:
"transforms.DateFormatTransformation.type": "org.example.DateTransformer"
the request is a constant Sending request... mode until the request expires. I tried adding
org.example.DateTransformer$Value as per the docs, but it gives me an error that such class doesn't exist.
I don't know what I am missing.
public class DateTransformer<R extends ConnectRecord<R>> implements Transformation<R> {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DateTransformer.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(R connectRecord) {
        Object value = connectRecord.value();

        if (value instanceof Struct) {
            Struct structValue = (Struct) value;
            if (structValue.schema().field("tomatoes") != null) {
                Struct tomatoes = structValue.getStruct("tomatoes");
                if (tomatoes != null && tomatoes.schema().field("lastUpdated") != null) {
                    String lastUpdated = tomatoes.getString("lastUpdated");
                    try {
                        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
                        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(lastUpdated);
                        tomatoes.put("lastUpdated", date);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        log.error("Failed to parse date: {}", lastUpdated, e);
                    }
                } else {
                    log.warn("'tomatoes' struct is null. Skipping transformation.");
                }
            } else {
                log.warn("Field 'tomatoes' not found in schema. Skipping transformation.");
            }
        } else {
            log.warn("Record value is not an instance of Struct. Skipping transformation.");
        }
        return connectRecord;
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigDef config() {
        return new ConfigDef();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

kafka record:
{
    "plot": "......",
    "genres": [
        "Comedy"
    ],
    "runtime": 71,
    "cast": [
        "Lois Wilson"
    ],
    "title": "Movie Title",
    "fullPlot": null,
    "countries": [
        "USA"
    ],
    "awards": {
        "wins": 1,
        "nominations": 0,
        "text": "1 win."
    },
    "year": 1921,
    "type": "movie",
    "tomatoes": {
        "rating": 2.5,
        "lastUpdated": 1430593428000
    },
    "released": -1520035200000,
    "recordCreatedOn":2024-11-11T08:33:02.543+00:00,
    "recordLastUpdatedOn":2024-11-11T08:33:02.543+00:00,
}

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>smt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect-transforms</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

properties.json
{
    "name": "mongodb-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "movies",
        "connection.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017/",
        "database": "movies",
        "collection": "movies",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "transforms": "AddRecordCreatedOn,FormatRecordCreatedOn,DateFormatTransformation",
        "transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.timestamp.field": "recordCreatedOn",
        "transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
        "transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.field": "recordCreatedOn",
        "transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.target.type": "Timestamp",
        "transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
        "transforms.DateFormatTransformation.type": "org.example.DateTransformer"
    }
}

connect-standalone.properties
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=D:/kafka/connect/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=1000

plugin.path=D:/kafka/connectors

These are the logs after starting .\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\config\connect-standalone.properties and passing the connectors via REST. The logs are exactly the same if I do it like this:
.\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\config\connect-standalone.properties .\config\connect-mongodb-source.properties .\config\connect-mongodb-sink.properties.
[2024-11-19 17:19:21,602] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli:120)
[2024-11-19 17:19:21,626] INFO Loading plugin from: D:\kafka\connectors\mongo-kafka-connect-1.13.0-confluent.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-11-19 17:19:21,814] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/D:/kafka/connectors/mongo-kafka-connect-1.13.0-confluent.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-11-19 17:19:21,816] INFO Loading plugin from: D:\kafka\connectors\smt-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-11-19 17:19:21,863] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/D:/kafka/connectors/smt-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-11-19 17:19:21,863] INFO Loading plugin from: classpath (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-11-19 17:19:21,876] INFO Registered loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5acf9800 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-11-19 17:19:21,877] INFO Scanning plugins with ServiceLoaderScanner took 254 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:70)
[2024-11-19 17:19:21,878] INFO Loading plugin from: D:\kafka\connectors\mongo-kafka-connect-1.13.0-confluent.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-11-19 17:19:22,149] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/D:/kafka/connectors/mongo-kafka-connect-1.13.0-confluent.jar} 
access.control.allow.methods =
access.control.allow.origin =
admin.listeners = null
auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
config.providers = []
connector.client.config.override.policy = All
header.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter
key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
listeners = [http://:8083]
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
offset.flush.interval.ms = 1000
offset.flush.timeout.ms = 5000
offset.storage.file.filename = D:/kafka/connect/connect.offsets
plugin.discovery = hybrid_warn
plugin.path = [D:/kafka/connectors]
response.http.headers.config =
rest.advertised.host.name = null
rest.advertised.listener = null
rest.advertised.port = null
rest.extension.classes = []
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.client.auth = none
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
topic.creation.enable = true
topic.tracking.allow.reset = true
topic.tracking.enable = true
value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneConfig:372)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,451] INFO Creating Kafka admin client (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig:283)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,456] INFO AdminClientConfig values:
auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
bootstrap.controllers = []
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id =
connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.metrics.push = true
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metadata.recovery.strategy = none
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.max.ms = 1000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
(org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:372)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,574] INFO These configurations '[offset.flush.interval.ms, key.converter.schemas.enable, offset.storage.file.filename, value.converter.schemas.enable, plugin.path, value.converter, key.converter]' were supplied but are not used yet. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:381)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,576] INFO Kafka version: 3.8.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:124)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,577] INFO Kafka commitId: 771b9576b00ecf5b (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:125)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,577] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1732029563575 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:126)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,814] INFO Kafka cluster ID: daqwrCtFQPyzbeevhFwA1A (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig:300)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,816] INFO App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:88)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,822] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:684)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,823] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:688)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,824] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:694)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,830] INFO PublicConfig values:
access.control.allow.methods =
access.control.allow.origin =
admin.listeners = null
listeners = [http://:8083]
response.http.headers.config =
rest.advertised.host.name = null
rest.advertised.listener = null
rest.advertised.port = null
rest.extension.classes = []
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.client.auth = none
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
topic.tracking.allow.reset = true
topic.tracking.enable = true
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServerConfig$PublicConfig:372)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,841] INFO Logging initialized @2708ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log:170)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,873] INFO Added connector for http://:8083 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:121)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,874] INFO Initializing REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:192)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,900] INFO jetty-9.4.54.v20240208; built: 2024-02-08T19:42:39.027Z; git: cef3fbd6d736a21e7d541a5db490381d95a2047d; jvm 21.0.2+13-LTS-58 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:375)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,935] INFO Started http_8083@192b472d{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:333)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,936] INFO Started @2803ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:415)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,953] INFO Advertised URI: http://192.168.1.3:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:412)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,954] INFO REST server listening at http://192.168.1.3:8083/, advertising URL http://192.168.1.3:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:212)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,955] INFO Advertised URI: http://192.168.1.3:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:412)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,955] INFO REST admin endpoints at http://192.168.1.3:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:215)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,956] INFO Advertised URI: http://192.168.1.3:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:412)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,957] INFO Setting up All Policy for ConnectorClientConfigOverride. This will allow all client configurations to be overridden (org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.AllConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy:44)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,958] INFO JsonConverterConfig values:
converter.type = key
decimal.format = BASE64
replace.null.with.default = true
schemas.cache.size = 1000
schemas.enable = false
(org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig:372)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,967] INFO Kafka version: 3.8.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:124)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,967] INFO Kafka commitId: 771b9576b00ecf5b (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:125)
[2024-11-19 17:19:23,969] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1732029563967 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:126)
writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@71d5f582]}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[com.mongodb.kafka.connect.util.ConnectionValidator$1@71c78d91]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=UNSPECIFIED, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null} (org.mongodb.driver.client:71)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,837] INFO Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:899}] to localhost:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.connection:71)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,837] INFO Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:898}] to localhost:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.connection:71)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,838] INFO Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=25, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=27288100} (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,857] INFO AbstractConfig values:
(org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:372)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,876] INFO [mongodb-sink|worker] Creating connector mongodb-sink of type com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:312)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,878] INFO [mongodb-sink|worker] SinkConnectorConfig values:
config.action.reload = restart
connector.class = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
errors.log.enable = false
errors.log.include.messages = false
errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
errors.retry.timeout = 0
errors.tolerance = none
header.converter = null
key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
name = mongodb-sink
predicates = []
tasks.max = 1
tasks.max.enforce = true
topics = [movies]
topics.regex =
transforms = [AddRecordCreatedOn, AddRecordLastUpdatedOn, FormatRecordCreatedOn, FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn, FormatReleasedToTimestamp, FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp, CustomSmt]
value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SinkConnectorConfig:372)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,882] INFO [mongodb-sink|worker] EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
config.action.reload = restart
connector.class = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
errors.log.enable = false
errors.log.include.messages = false
errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
errors.retry.timeout = 0
errors.tolerance = none
header.converter = null
key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
name = mongodb-sink
predicates = []
tasks.max = 1
tasks.max.enforce = true
topics = [movies]
topics.regex =
transforms = [AddRecordCreatedOn, AddRecordLastUpdatedOn, FormatRecordCreatedOn, FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn, FormatReleasedToTimestamp, FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp, CustomSmt]
transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.negate = false
transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.offset.field = null
transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.partition.field = null
transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.predicate = null
transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.static.field = null
transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.static.value = null
transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.timestamp.field = recordCreatedOn
transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.topic.field = null
transforms.AddRecordCreatedOn.type = class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
transforms.AddRecordLastUpdatedOn.negate = false
transforms.AddRecordLastUpdatedOn.offset.field = null
transforms.AddRecordLastUpdatedOn.partition.field = null
transforms.AddRecordLastUpdatedOn.predicate = null
transforms.AddRecordLastUpdatedOn.static.field = null
transforms.AddRecordLastUpdatedOn.static.value = null
transforms.AddRecordLastUpdatedOn.timestamp.field = recordLastUpdatedOn
transforms.AddRecordLastUpdatedOn.topic.field = null
transforms.AddRecordLastUpdatedOn.type = class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
transforms.CustomSmt.negate = false
transforms.CustomSmt.predicate = null
transforms.CustomSmt.type = class org.example.DateTransformer
transforms.FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp.field = released
transforms.FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp.format = yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
transforms.FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp.negate = false
transforms.FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp.predicate = null
transforms.FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp.target.type = Timestamp
transforms.FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp.type = class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp.unix.precision = milliseconds
transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.field = recordCreatedOn
transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.format = yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.negate = false
transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.predicate = null
transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.target.type = Timestamp
transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.type = class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.FormatRecordCreatedOn.unix.precision = milliseconds
transforms.FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn.field = recordLastUpdatedOn
transforms.FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn.format = yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
transforms.FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn.negate = false
transforms.FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn.predicate = null
transforms.FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn.target.type = Timestamp
transforms.FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn.type = class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn.unix.precision = milliseconds
transforms.FormatReleasedToTimestamp.field = lastUpdated
transforms.FormatReleasedToTimestamp.format = yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
transforms.FormatReleasedToTimestamp.negate = false
transforms.FormatReleasedToTimestamp.predicate = null
transforms.FormatReleasedToTimestamp.target.type = Timestamp
transforms.FormatReleasedToTimestamp.type = class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.FormatReleasedToTimestamp.unix.precision = milliseconds
value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig:372)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,887] INFO [mongodb-sink|worker] Instantiated connector mongodb-sink with version 1.13.0 of type class com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:334)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,889] INFO [mongodb-sink|worker] Finished creating connector mongodb-sink (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:355)
[2024-11-19 17:19:26,894] INFO SinkConnectorConfig values:
config.action.reload = restart
connector.class = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
errors.log.enable = false
errors.log.include.messages = false
errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
errors.retry.timeout = 0
errors.tolerance = none
header.converter = null
key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
name = mongodb-sink
predicates = []
tasks.max = 1
tasks.max.enforce = true
topics = [movies]
topics.regex =
transforms = [AddRecordCreatedOn, AddRecordLastUpdatedOn, FormatRecordCreatedOn, FormatRecordLastUpdatedOn, FormatReleasedToTimestamp, FormatLastUpdatedToTimestamp, CustomSmt]
value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SinkConnectorConfig:372)



"added it to my connectors path - How? 2) Please share logs


@OneCricketeer 1) I mean I have added my .jar connector, which I have created, to my kafka/connectors folder, which hosts all connectors and to which plugin.path property in the connect-standalone.properties points. 2) this is an excerpt of the logs, just after I try to add the problematic connector line 'org.example.DateTransformer' ....


Please [edit] to include your standalone configs and logs 2) Standalone server uses properties files to start connectors, not JSON


@OneCricketeer

I added the properties file
You can both pass the .properties files as parameters when you are the standalone.bat or pass them as JSON via REST endpoint which connect-standalone.bat creates. I have used both interchangeably.


Also, here are the full logs from starting the connect-standalone.bat to loading the properties- https://rentry.co/984av6se. Basically the moment I click Send in Postman with the above-mentioned JSON properties, the request loads forever and just times out.


[Edit] the post instead 2) As mentioned, connect-standalone does not run a server that you can POST to


@OneCricketeer 1) I already provided the link, I can't just put 500 lines of code as a comment 2) kafka connect is a service and accepts REST API requests on port 8083 by default. I always submit connectors via http://localhost:8083/connectors. You can check official docs here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html

Don't put 500 lines, then? Put the most relevant. I don't know what rentry.co is, and I am not going to open random links on my work computer (no offense). 2) Thanks, I am Kafka certified and contribute to the code, I know how Connect API works... But run connect-standalone.sh --help and look at the arguments. You pass the JSON/property files to that, rather than the REST API. You should only use the REST API with connect-distributed.sh.


I will add the logs. 2) I respect that you are a Kafka certified and contribute to the code, but this doesn't change the fact that I can submit connectors via REST endpoints when running connect-standalone.bat. It is said in the documentation. I have done either ways - passing the properties as params - .\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\config\connect-standalone.properties .\config\connect-mongodb-source.properties .\config\connect-mongodb-sink.properties and passing them separarely via the endpoints. Both ways work, only the custom connector doesn't.


Thanks. I don't have access to your JAR file, but INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/D:/kafka/connectors/smt-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar means it was found, and should exist. I do not see any error here that says ClassNotFound, so where do you see that, exactly?

Well, I didn't say it wasn't found but that it wasn't accepted, or more precisely the code isn't executed. Also, I don't see any logs from the DateTransfomer, so I guess the apply code isn't executed at all and I don't understand why. Also, no logs from the DateTransfomer are present. Even if something failed, at least one log should have been printed.

When you set schemas.enable=false for JSONConverter, you won't have a valueSchema

I will try to include a schema using a KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer but I have big problems running Confluent Platform on Windows for now. But I am not sure the schema itself would solve the problem.

You don't need Confluent Platform (or Schema Registry) to solve that problem. You can just rewrite your SMT. Java runs in any OS. Use WSL2 if "Windows" is really a problem... I also maintain a Docker image for Connect to test my plugins

What exactly should I rewrite in it? I really don't see where the problem can be.

SMT must be written in JVM code, so Java, Scala, Kotlin etc. My point was that you don't need a Schema Registry, just a schema

I don't understand what I have to do. I already have the connector written and I don't know how this schema fits into the picture e.g. where should I put it. My guess is that the Struct relies on a JSON structure where I have a schema and payload, but I am not sure about this.

That's correct. https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/

I am not able to do it so I guess I will leave it as it is.

Just add code that checks for string schema and use a JSON parser to get a pojo. Rest of the code will be similar
